# A jQuery "bug" for the pros- alert makes it work

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function on click that toggles a div.  It checks the classes to determine if it should remove the 'hilighted' state classes.

This fails to remove the holdhilite class:

```
function togglediv(id){
    //alert('toggle id= '+id);
    $("#"+id).toggle("fast");
    if(window.location.hash.split("#")[1]==justtheid(id)){
        var scr = document.body.scrollTop;
        window.location.href = '#';
        document.body.scrollTop = scr;          
    }       
    var trid = "tr_"+justtheid(id);
    if($("#"+trid).attr('class')=='holdhilight rowhover'){
        $("#"+trid).removeClass('holdhilight');         
    }
    else{
        $("#"+trid).addClass('holdhilight');            
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this works 100%:

```
function togglediv(id){
    alert('toggle id= '+id);
    $("#"+id).toggle("fast");
    if(window.location.hash.split("#")[1]==justtheid(id)){
        var scr = document.body.scrollTop;
        window.location.href = '#';
        document.body.scrollTop = scr;          
    }       
    var trid = "tr_"+justtheid(id);
    if($("#"+trid).attr('class')=='holdhilight rowhover'){
        $("#"+trid).removeClass('holdhilight');                         
    }
    else{
        $("#"+trid).addClass('holdhilight');            
    }
}
```

Note the only difference is that alert being uncommented (i don't even want to tell you how long it took me to figure out this was the issue...  lol)

So, what's the deal?  why does waiting/clicking ok on the alert allow the class=='holdhilight rowhover' to match but when no alert, it does not (even though an alert in this spot says it DOES indeed match, but once the alert is in place, it works again... lol)

I've waiting in my browser 30 seconds before trying to close it, and that did nothing to fix it.  It's not the script taking forever to run.

This is all wrapped in a ready() function anyway.

I'm in an ie8-specific enviro (intranet) using the latest 1.9

Comment: how is togglediv being called? sounds like a race condition, like possibly clicking on an anchor that has a # in it's href. If that's the case and you aren't preventing default, the browser first does your event, then follows the href which undoes your scroll change.

Comment: What's your `ready()` function look like?

Comment: Perhaps you are executing this before the DOM has fully loaded.  The alert gives time for that to happen in the background.

Comment: I would hesitate making claims of a jQuery bug. If something starts working with an alert interrupting the current thread the first thought coming to mind is race-condition as mentioned or you are expecting something to exist which is not yet available/rendered/loaded, etc..

Comment: @SteveH. The OP mentions that he's wrapped the code in a `ready()` function so that's likely not the case.

Comment: Instead of using alert, place a few `console.log()` instructions into your code and watch the outputs. Say for example `console.log($("#"+id).length)`, `console.log($("#"+trid).length)`, `console.log(justtheid(id))` and where ever else you can place one. That way you get better information on what is available and what is not. Unlike `alert()` , `console.log()` won't interrupt the execution and the outputs are more accurate and true.

Comment: Create a reproduction of the problem on jsFiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, Filddle is blocked at my work :(
I am calling it via a click, like
$('.vm').click(function(e) {   
  var id = e.target.id;
  togglediv(id);    
 });

Comment: Also, as stated, it's in a big $(document).ready(function() { call, so the body should be rendered before even being invoked.
further, the set works just fine.  it's the class remove that fails.
i'll look more into the race conditions.
And note, i used 'bug' in quotes.  I'm not accusing anyone or anything here...  just experiencing said bug with my code.   I'll try the loging and report back later today.   Thanks for the advice so far.

Comment: I've logged everything, successfully.  no errors. all conditions match as they should.

I added in a custom 'sleep' function.  it also fails, just takes longer to do so.
an alert, no matter how slow or fast i work it, nor no matter the position within the toggle function (can be before or after the class removal) makes it work.  without it, it simply doesn't remove the class.  

Im completely stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by using the action handler as a function to do the other stuff.  This should have been obvious and i feel dumb answering it, but hey, maybe it helps someone else down the road.

```
$('#'+id).toggle('fast', function() {
//all the hash location stuff here will fire after the toggle is done. 
});
```